# Spanish characters with Trebuchet font?

Tags: html, css, fonts

When using 
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
in photoshop, Spanish characters show up fine. On the website they show up as �.

I've done some research with changing
    
but it doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

Is this a problem with the font or with HTML in general and how can I get around it? Thanks!

Comment: with changing <meta charset="UTF-8">, my apoloties

Comment: Is your HTML output actually in UTF-8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem,  it has happened me several times.

This is probably not the easiest way to solve it. 
For example, a "!" upside down is

```
&iexcl;
```

or

```
&#161;
```

¡ and ¡

Check out [this page](http://www.tiger.se/dok/koder.html)
or  [this page](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/sgml/entities.html) for more info